# Sql Query in Typed Dataset causing Parser Error

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, syntax-error, strongly-typed-dataset

I have the this SQL query in a typed dataset in asp.net 2005 and SQL Server 2008 R2.
i.e  I have used in Typed Dataset -- "Add Query" -- "Use Sql Statements" and used the below script, then I returned a Datatable. ("Fill a Datatable" checkbox was unchecked")

```
SELECT DISTINCT
ISNULL(Projects.ProjectID,'0') as 
ProjectID,Messages.MessageID, Projects.ProjectName, Customers.CustomerName as 
CustomerName, Regions.RegionName,
(select U.firstName + ' ' + U.LastName 
 from Users U inner join Projects P on P.ProjectManagerId = U.UserID inner join   
 Messages M on M.ProjectId = P.ProjectID
 where M.MessageID =  Messages.MessageID) as ProjectManagerName,
 dbo.phases.TagName as Phase,
(select U.firstName + ' ' + U.LastName 
from Users U inner join  Messages M on M.CreatedBy = U.UserID Where M.MessageID =   
Messages.MessageID) as CreatedBy,
Messages.DateCreated as EmailCreatedDate,
Messages.MessageSubject as MessageSubject,
Users.Email as [From],
**(stuff((select ','+U.EMAIL
FROM USERS U INNER JOIN Recipients R ON U.USERID = R.USERID INNER JOIN MESSAGES M   
ON  R.MESSAGEID = M.MESSAGEID
          WHERE m.MessageID=Messages.MessageID AND R.RecipientTypeID=1
          for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')) as [TO],**

  **(stuff((select ','+U.EMAIL 
          FROM USERS U INNER JOIN Recipients R ON U.USERID = R.USERID INNER JOIN    
MESSAGES M ON R.MESSAGEID = M.MESSAGEID
          WHERE m.MessageID=Messages.MessageID AND R.RecipientTypeID=2
          for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')) as CC** 


FROM     Messages INNER JOIN  Users 
              ON Messages.Sender = Users.UserID
              INNER JOIN Recipients
              ON Messages.MessageID = Recipients.MessageID
              LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Projects 
              ON dbo.Messages.ProjectID = dbo.Projects.ProjectID                      
              Left OUTER JOIN dbo.Customers on dbo.Projects.CustomerId =  
dbo.Customers.CustomerID 
              Left outer join dbo.regions on dbo.Customers.RegionID =  
dbo.Regions.RegionID
              left outer join dbo.Phases on messages.phaseid = dbo.phases.phaseid

where (Messages.MessageTypeID=1)
and Projects.ProjectID <> '0' 
order by Projects.ProjectName
```

But on clicking next , it is causing an error like this:

> Error in WHERE clause near '('.
>   Unable to parse query text.

However If I run the same above query in SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio, it runs fine and returns the results.

Please suggest what am I doing wrong.

Thanks

---

Hi, I have used one way out for this..ie used this Query(after slight modification) as inline query in .cs code behind file.. but now another problem is arising....ie. 
Now it is taking too much of time to return results.. is it because of the functions I have used in the query ? please suggest some workaround for this..

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
   ISNULL(Projects.ProjectID,'0') as 
   ProjectID,Messages.MessageID, Projects.ProjectName, Customers.CustomerName as  CustomerName, Regions.RegionName,  
   (select U.firstName + ' ' + U.LastName 
     from Users U inner join Projects P on P.ProjectManagerId = U.UserID inner join Messages M on M.ProjectId = P.ProjectID
     where M.MessageID =  Messages.MessageID) as ProjectManagerName,
     dbo.phases.TagName as Phase,
     (select U.firstName + ' ' + U.LastName 
     from Users U inner join  Messages M on M.CreatedBy = U.UserID Where M.MessageID = Messages.MessageID) as CreatedBy,
     Messages.DateCreated as EmailCreatedDate,
     Messages.MessageSubject as MessageSubject,
     Users.Email as [From],

    (select [dbo].[fn_ForEmailReport](Messages.MessageID,1)) as [TO],
    (select [dbo].[fn_ForEmailReport](Messages.MessageID,2)) as [CC]

    FROM     Messages INNER JOIN  Users 
                      ON Messages.Sender = Users.UserID
                      INNER JOIN Recipients
                      ON Messages.MessageID = Recipients.MessageID
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Projects 
                      ON dbo.Messages.ProjectID = dbo.Projects.ProjectID                      
                      Left OUTER JOIN dbo.Customers on dbo.Projects.CustomerId = dbo.Customers.CustomerID 
                      Left outer join dbo.regions on dbo.Customers.RegionID = dbo.Regions.RegionID
                      left outer join dbo.Phases on messages.phaseid = dbo.phases.phaseid

    where (Messages.MessageTypeID=1)
    and Projects.ProjectID <> '0' 
    order by Projects.ProjectName


-- FUNCTION "fn_ForEmailReport" used in above query.

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ForEmailReport]
(
    @MessageID int,
    @RecipientTypeID int
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)        
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @List VARCHAR(8000)
    set @List = (stuff((select ','+U.EMAIL 
    FROM USERS U inner JOIN Recipients R ON R.USERID = U.USERID inner JOIN 
            MESSAGES M ON R.MESSAGEID = M.MESSAGEID
    WHERE m.MessageID=@MessageID AND R.RecipientTypeID=@RecipientTypeID
    for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''))

  RETURN @List;
```

END

Comment: Have you tried without paranthesis? like where Messages.MessageTypeID=1
and Projects.ProjectID <> '0'

Comment: I edited the original query so please review and suggest

Answer (score 0):

There are too many joins I believe. For example, the query below

```
(select U.firstName + ' ' + U.LastName 
from Users U inner join Projects P 
on P.ProjectManagerId = U.UserID 
inner join Messages M on M.ProjectId = P.ProjectID
where M.MessageID =  Messages.MessageID) as ProjectManagerName,
```

gets only a firstname and lastname, a cell, it doesn't need to be a join query. Plus, you have already joined Projects table at the end. You can give an alias to outer query and make inner queries simpler:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   ISNULL(Projects.ProjectID,'0') as 
   ProjectID,Messages.MessageID, Projects.ProjectName, Customers.CustomerName as  CustomerName, Regions.RegionName,  
   (select U.firstName + ' ' + U.LastName 
     from Users WHERE P.ProjectManagerId = UserID) as ProjectManagerName,
     dbo.phases.TagName as Phase,
     (select U.firstName + ' ' + U.LastName 
     from Users WHERE M.CreatedBy = UserID) as CreatedBy,
     Messages.DateCreated as EmailCreatedDate,
     Messages.MessageSubject as MessageSubject,
     Users.Email as [From],

    (select [dbo].[fn_ForEmailReport](Messages.MessageID,1)) as [TO],
    (select [dbo].[fn_ForEmailReport](Messages.MessageID,2)) as [CC]

    FROM     Messages M INNER JOIN  Users 
                      ON Messages.Sender = Users.UserID
                      INNER JOIN Recipients
                      ON Messages.MessageID = Recipients.MessageID
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Projects P
                      ON dbo.Messages.ProjectID = dbo.Projects.ProjectID                      
                      Left OUTER JOIN dbo.Customers on dbo.Projects.CustomerId = dbo.Customers.CustomerID 
                      Left outer join dbo.regions on dbo.Customers.RegionID = dbo.Regions.RegionID
                      left outer join dbo.Phases on messages.phaseid = dbo.phases.phaseid

    where (Messages.MessageTypeID=1)
    and Projects.ProjectID <> '0' 
    order by Projects.ProjectName
```

Finally, if you don't retrieve any information from Customers table, you can omit the following line:

```
Left OUTER JOIN dbo.Customers on dbo.Projects.CustomerId = dbo.Customers.CustomerID
```